# RichTextBox SelectionColor changes as I change the Font size

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I change the Selection BackColor and ForeColor in some parts of a RichTextBox.
After changing the Font size using the following code the selection color changes to black:

```
 RichTextBox5.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(
     "Times New Roman", RichTextBox5.Font.Size - 0.1F, FontStyle.Regular)
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You should have taken the site tour when prompted and then spent some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: This doesn't usually happen, so you need to specify how the selection was made. Post all the code needed to reproduce the issue (test yourself that the code you're about to post actually reproduces the behavior you're describing). Also post the .Net version in use.